# Separating special characters and display them

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with a column Name, like this:

```
Name
ftyrt_hghjh
hgdhfg_jhjh
dfgfh#hvhvj
vhhghf=dvdf
hdghfg%bdjfb
```

I want to separate the special characters and display them like below:

```
Name             Special_Char
ftyrt_hghjh          _    
hgdhfg_jhjh          _
dfgfh#hvhvj          #
vhhghf=dvdf          =
hdghfg%bdjfb         %
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with temp as 
(select 'ftyrt_hghjh' as name from dual
 union all
select 'hgdhfg_jhjh' as name from dual
 union all
select 'dfgfh#hvhvj' as name from dual
 union all
select 'vhhghf=dvdf' as name from dual
 union all
select 'hdghfg%bdjfb' as name from dual
)
select name AS "Name"
      ,regexp_substr(name, '[^a-zA-Z]') AS "Special Character"
from temp
```

match any character other than `a-z` or `A-Z` with regexp
[Match Special Character](http://rextester.com/LDVW61103)

Comment: can we write a without Temp

Comment: @Gunnu - the 'Temp' sub query is just a way to select from some basic test data. You will, presumably, have a table of your own with that data. Substitute that instead of the 'from temp' on the last line.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function translate to replace all non-special characters with nothing, actually removing them from the input string.

Assuming the special characters are

> _ # = %

and assuming the non-special characters are all lowercase from a to z
the following will work:

```
translate (table.name, '_#=%abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', '_#=%')
```